# How do I make a switch statement repeat?

Tags: java, switch-statement, repeat

```
canner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

int userNum;


int computerNum = (int) (0 + Math.random() * 3);

System.out.println("Let's play rock paper scissors.");
System.out.println("Choose rock paper or scissors");

boolean input = false;

String userInput = Input.nextLine();

do {
switch (userInput.toLowerCase().trim()) {
    case "rock":
        userNum = 0;
        input = true;
        break;
    case "paper":
        userNum = 1;
        input = true;
        break;
    case "scissors:":
        userNum = 2;
        input = true;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Please retry and make sure spelling is correct");
        input = false;
        break;
}
} while (input = false);
```

Comment: What is wrong? What is the desired behavior? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I make a switch statement repeat?

General answer:  you put a loop around it.

In this case, the problem is that you have made a mistake in the loop.

Specifically:

```
    } while (input = false);
```

is **assigning** `false` to `input`.  The value of the assignment `input = false` is `false` ... so your loop statement only executes the loop body once.

It should be this:

```
    } while (input == false);
```

Or better still<sup>1</sup>:

```
   }  while (!input);
```

---

<sup>1 - It is better because when you use `==` to test a boolean, there is a risk that you will accidentally use `=` instead ... with the consequences illustrated above!  Note that in Java this problem only applies to `boolean` tests.  For other types, `x = y` will have a different type to `x == y` and is sufficient for the mistake to result in a compilation error ... which is a GOOD thing, in this context.</sup>